# How can I remove duplicate code from my jquery function?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery and implemented following function in a js file in case of error-

```
function before_submit_check_if_has_blank_field() {
    $("[type=submit]").click(function(e) {
        var of_key_field = $('.key_field')
        var of_val_field = $('.val_field')
        var should_run = 1

        if (of_key_field.length === 1) {
            $('.key_field:not(:first)').filter(function() {
                if (this.value === "") {
                    alert('Please Fill In Or Remove The Blank Fields First')
                    e.preventDefault();
                    should_run = 0
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('.key_field').filter(function() {
                if (this.value === "") {
                    alert('Please Fill In Or Remove The Blank Fields First')
                    e.preventDefault();
                    should_run = 0
                }
            });
        }

        if (should_run != 0) {
            if (of_val_field.length === 1) {
                $('.val_field:not(:first)').filter(function() {
                    if (this.value === "") {
                        alert('Please Fill In Or Remove The Blank Fields First')
                        e.preventDefault();
                        should_run = 0
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('.val_field').filter(function() {
                    if (this.value === "") {
                        alert('Please Fill In Or Remove The Blank Fields First')
                        e.preventDefault();
                        should_run = 0
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        update_config_field_from_key_value_field()
    });
}
```

Here I am repeating following lines and must be replaced by standard one-

```
if (this.value === "") {
                        alert('Please Fill In Or Remove The Blank Fields First')
                        e.preventDefault();
                        should_run = 0
                    }
```

Can you please help me how can I refactor my code so that it looks nicer?

Comment: If it works, you may want to post this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, it  doesn't look like it should work though as you return nothing in the filter so it won't filter anything

Comment: Thanks @Pete! I will post my question there.

Comment: @Pete I have tested the code and it shows alert message in case of blank field.

Comment: you probably want to use an [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) instead of a [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) as you are not really filtering (and the code could confuse future developers)

Comment: actually I am using the filter here-
$('.val_field:not(:first)').filter(function() {

to use this not(:first)

Comment: if you're not returning anything in the function then you're not using the filter, you are filtering in your selector, but then you have already filtered and can still use an each.  Anyway, if you don't want to listen to how to improve your code then why ask the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break your code into smaller functions.

```
function emptyHandle(e, should_run) {
    alert('Please Fill In Or Remove The Blank Fields First');
    e.preventDefault();
    should_run = 0;
}
function isEmpty(element) {
    return element.val() === "";
}
function before_submit_check_if_has_blank_field() {
    $("[type=submit]").click(function (e) {
        var of_key_field = $('.key_field')
        var of_val_field = $('.val_field')
        var should_run = 1

        if (of_key_field.length === 1) {
            if (isEmpty($('.key_field:not(:first)'))) emptyHandle(e,should_run);
        } else {
            if (isEmpty($('.key_field'))) emptyHandle(e,should_run);
        }

        if (!should_run) {
            if (of_val_field.length === 1 && isEmpty($('.val_field:not(:first)'))) {
                emptyHandle(e,should_run);
            } else {
                if (isEmpty($('.val_field'))) emptyHandle(e,should_run);
            }
        }

        update_config_field_from_key_value_field()
    });
}
```